# ESQ/POS via javapos TSP700II

Tags: thermal-printer, javapos

I'm trying to make a receipt printer (TSP700II) print via javapos in ESQ/POS-mode in windows7.

I can print fine via javapos in line-mode and also iin ESQ/POS-mode via the windows print queue.

I try to print via javapos inESQ/POS-mode, by including this line in jpos.xml:

```
<prop name="emulation" type="String" value="ESC/POS" />
```

and I also tried to turn on jumper #1 on the bottom of the printer.

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.starmicronics.starjavapos.ESCPOS.POSPrinterESCPOSThermal
```

, this class is not part of the any of the .jar-files in the javapos driver package from Star Micronics (starjavapos_1.13.10_windows_32bit_20160621). This package has a nice example printing line-mode via javapos and it works fine, but there is no ESQ/POS example and I can't find any on the internet either.

What am I doing wrong ?

I first tried with a TSP100, but can't print ESP/POS via javapos. But a TSP700II should be able to do so.

Comment: Are you installing and setting up according to this [Star JavaPOS Driver Software Manual](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/Mannualfolder/starjavapos_sm_en.pdf)? The property named "emulation" does not seem to exist. Please follow the instructions in the manual. Besides, if you are using 32bit mode with 64bit OS, please pay attention to general precautions when mixing 64bit/32bit.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure because the samples run just fine. But I don't know what I need to change to make it print in ESC/POS. Are there any special methods I should use ? Is there an example somewhere ?

Comment: Why would you like to use ESC/POS mode? The [software installation manual](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/MannualFolder/Software_im_en.pdf) says that OPOS can not be used in ESC/POS mode. There is no description about JavaPOS, but JavaPOS and OPOS are equivalent, considering functions and specifications. If you really want to use the ESC/POS mode, you may think of sending a print command directly using the serial/parallel port instead of JavaPOS/OPOS, or installing WindowsPrinterDriver and using it as a WindowsPrinter.

Comment: We want to use ESC/POS mode because we already have our reports designed in ESC/POS codes. Now we need to take advantage of the services that javapos offers - notification on OutOfPaper, NearOutOfPaper and lidOpen. I read somewhere that TSP100 only can do line mode in javapos but TSP700II can also do ESC/POS

Comment: Usually, JavaPOS/OPOS occupies the device. You say that receipt printing is done by sending conventional ESC/POS command and JavaPOS is used to detect the status of paper and cover, but these functions are exclusively used and should be executed at the same time You can not. When using JavaPOS/OPOS, receipt printing also needs to be done within the functional range of escape sequence defined by JavaPOS/OPOS with JavaPOS/OPOS PrintNormal method.

Comment: Even without using JavaPOS/OPOS, you can analyze the results of DLE EOT and the ASB, which are notified from the printer, and check the state of paper and cover. Refer to 6-2 Appendix 2 Status Specifications of [this manual](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/Mannualfolder/escpos_cm_en.pdf). However, ASB can be notified only in the Line mode on USB I/F printers as shown at the beginning of 6-2-4 ASB Status Specifications.